# Back button and ActionbarUpButton close app instead of going back

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my MainActivity I have a SlidingTabBar, and from those Tabs (Fragments) I open other Activities on certain events (like FAB-onClick). Now when I'm on an opened Activity and press the back-button on the device or the HomeAsUp (back) button in the Actionbar, I want to go back to the Fragment on the MainActivity from where I opened the other Activity, but the App just closes.

I dont have any onBackPressed methods and I dont call finsish() anywhere in the Activities I open.
I just call them with an intent from the Fragment:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), OfferActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

I have this methode in my MainActivity, because from there I want to be able to quit the app with the back button:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   finish();
}
```

I also have a LoginActivity from where I call the MainActivity this way (it is a FacebookLogin, so it is only nessecary once at opening the app the first time):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(intent.getFlags() | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

If you need any other code please tell me :)

EDIT: Here is the code how I add Fragments to the TabLayout in my MainActivity:

```
private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    adapter.addFragment(new NewsFragment(), "NEWS");
    adapter.addFragment(new ProfileFragment(), "PROFILE");
    adapter.addFragment(new NotificationFragment(), "NOTIF");
    adapter.addFragment(new AboutFragment(), "ABOUT");

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}

class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        //return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);

        // null -> just use icons
        return null;
    }
}
```

EDIT 2: This is my Manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name=".adapter.AppController">
<activity
        android:name=".main.LoginActivity"
        android:label="friendlyride">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity
        android:name=".main.MainActivity"
        android:label="friendlyride">
</activity>
<activity
        android:name=".main.OfferActivity"
        android:label="Offer ride"
        android:parentActivityName=".main.MainActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".main.MainActivity"
            />
</activity>
</application>
```

The main.MainActivity is where my TabLayout is and main.OfferActivity is what I want to open from the Fragment. The main.LoginActivity has the intent-filter since it's the first Activity when I'm not already logged in (I dont now if this  intent-filter matters :))

FINAL EDIT:
I just found the problem. I open the MainActivity (from where I open everything else) from my LoginActivity with NO_HISTORY and CLEAR_TOP flags. And apperently these flags were also used for the Intents on the MainActivity, even though i didn't set them. I did not know that flags are "remembered" on following activities, even though I use new Intent without flags. Thank you for all your answers. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'll try this again as I didn't read the question carefully enough.

So if you have activity A launch activity B, in your AndroidManifest.xml you should have:

```
<manifest>
  <application>
     <activity android:name=".ActivityA" ...etc >
     <activity
        android:name=".ActivityB"
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="my.package.name.ActivityA" />
    </activity>
... closing tags
```

Note that `android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY` in Activity B points to `my.package.name.ActivityA`.

If that doesn't help can you provide your AndroidManifest.xml file?

Comment: Thanks again, my Manifest looks similar. I have added what I think are the important parts. If you need more please let me know :)

Answer (score 1):

You should do this.

In your manifest file define the parent for each of your activities, this will be the activities that are going to be called when user press back button, if there isn't any it closes the application.

so do something like this.

```
<activity
            android:name="com.youtpath.yourActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
              android:value="com.yourPath.theMainActivityActivity" />
```

This will solve the problem of getting back, yet you have to add the "singleTask" launchMode parameter so that there is only one instance of your MainActivity, avoiding the creation of another MainActivity when you press back.

Regarding the fragments, the FragmentManager is an Activity field, not from the application, so you cant call the fragments back stack from the new Activity because there isn't any.

Your problem is not navigation between fragments, but navigating from Activities.

Hope it solves the issue.

:)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I just found the problem. I opened the MainActivity (from where I open everything else) from my LoginActivity with NO_HISTORY and CLEAR_TOP flags. And apperently these flags were also used for the Intents on the MainActivity, even though i didn't set them. :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add your Fragment visit to the backstack.

See [Providing Proper Back Navigation](http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/temporal.html).

Specifically the Implement Back Navigation for Fragments:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                       .add(detailFragment, "detail")
                       // Add this transaction to the back stack
                       .addToBackStack()
                       .commit();
```

Comment: Thanks, I have looked it up but I dont know how to use it when I dont use Transactions. I have added the code how I add my Fragments to the TabLayout if you can help me further. :)

Comment: And establishing the parent activity in the manifest, doesnt solve the problem?

Comment: As said before, I added my Fragments like in the code above, so I didnt use a Transaction. So I dont know how to call the popBackStack to get back to the Fragment because I never add it to the backstack. :)

Comment: Sorry I read the question too quickly. I though the problem was going back from a fragment, not from an activity. @DanielOrdoñez is correct - try that.